# MacBook Pro 2016 (sans touchbar) – headphone jack not going all the way in

Tags: macbook-pro, headphones

I just bought a new MacBook Pro 2016 (without touchbar) and noticed that the headphone jack doesn't go all the way in and sticks out a couple of millimetres:
[image]

Despite that it seems to be working fine. However, I'm still worried that something might be broken inside and it will come up later.

Is it supposed to be that way on the new models?

Comment: Nope, seems like a bad cable. Try pushing harder? Try a different cable? Don't worry about it?

Comment: I think it should be like that, because on my 2016 MBP 15" it is also like that.

Comment: The question is...does your headphone work properly?  If it does, then then jack is *working*.  It may not fit *properly* but it's working.

Comment: Check if there is something stuck in the headphone jack!!! If there is and you keep pushing, you'll just make it worse.

Answer (score -2):

My MBP 13" with Touchbar won't fit all the way in either. Probably this is Apple's intention.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  It's also not a good idea to speculate on "Apple's intentions" as only they know what they intend.. Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Comment: I'm very new here. Thank you for your suggestion. 
I do understand that this is not an answer and it should be written to comment section. Yet I don't have enough reputation to comment on a question directly. My intention is to share information rather than to answer the question itself. If there is a better to contribute, I would love to know more about it.